# How to remove particular element from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like `treeids = ['a','b','c','d'];`
I want to remove the 'b' element. By Using index we can do, but i want this with out using index, because those values comes dynamically into this array.
Just remove with the name only.
It should support in IE7 browser.
How to do this.

Thanks

Comment: http://briancray.com/2009/09/30/remove-value-javascript-array/

Comment: Remove just the first instance, or all instances of the element?

Comment: @Jon all instances of the element

Comment: Any thing wrong in my question why two votes down.. strange.. any way thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript 1.6 provides [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which would suit your needs spot on.

Of course, as you can see from the Browser support table at the bottom, if you must support IE older then IE 9, you're out of luck.

jQuery provides [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) which does the same thing, but introduces the overhead of a separate library.

Underscore.js has [_.filter](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter), but again, this would be using a separate library for only one purpose.

Comment: But is it avaliable in IE 7 as the OP asks for?

Comment: @Jon: no, it is not, as you can see from my expanded response.

Comment: @Nikc...How to do the same thing with jquery.grep?

Comment: @Mihir: It's a link to the documentation, which contains an example.

Comment: See the [compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) for an implementation that can be used to add this functionality to older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
treeids.splice(treeids.indexOf('b'), 1);
```

Now treeids will contain the remaining...Here `'b'` was the element to be removed. The argument of `indexOf` can come from a variable. Additionally you should check for error: the index shouldn't be -1.

Answer (score 0):

This removes all the 'b's:

```
Array.prototype.remove= function(item){
    var L= this.length, indexed;
    while(L){
        indexed= this[--L];
        if(indexed=== itm) this.splice(L, 1);
    }
    return this;
}
```

splice is available in IE7 (and 6). It removes the number of items passed in the second argument, starting at the index specified by the first.

Comment: This needs some explanation to go with it.